# How to add buttons inline in a vertical scroll view

Tags: android, xml, android-studio, android-layout

In Android Studio I am try to make a scrollable section where there is two buttons and some text on each row. The scrollable is only letting me put one element per row. What am I doing wrong?

```
<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/guideline8"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/guideline6"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/guideline7"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/guideline5">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView3"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="TextView" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button9"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Button" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button8"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Button" />
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: show your layout's xml please

Comment: You have to show us at least some of your code so we can see what you are doing wrong

Comment: if I understand your mean, you want to put more than one element per row, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using a Linear Layout. It only allows one element per row/column.
To have multiple elements in a row or column, you would use a Constraint Layout or GridView.
However, if you are making a list, I would recommend you to use a RecyclerView.